# Why do the coherence rules raise the error "the type parameter must be used as the type parameter for some local type"?

Tags: rust

Why does code example 1 compile but example 2 gives a compilation error?

Example 1:

```
use std::ops::Index;

struct Bounded {
    idx: usize,
}

impl Index<Bounded> for [i32; 4] {
    type Output = i32;

    fn index(&self, b: Bounded) -> &i32 {
        unsafe { self.get_unchecked(b.idx) }
    }
}
```

Example 2:

```
use std::ops::Index;

struct Bounded {
    idx: usize,
}

impl<T> Index<Bounded> for [T; 4] {
    type Output = T;

    fn index(&self, b: Bounded) -> &T {
        unsafe { self.get_unchecked(b.idx) }
    }
}
```

```
error[E0210]: type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type (e.g. `MyStruct<T>`)
 --> src/main.rs:7:1
  |
7 | impl<T> Index<Bounded> for [T; 4] {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type
  |
  = note: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter
```

Comment: The problem here is actually orphan rule, not coherence rule :). You can check the explanation with `rustc --explain E0210`.

Comment: @kennytm: Shouldn't that be an answer (with some elaboration)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does boil down to "there's a good reason", but the good reason isn't all that complicated.

Here's the problem. Imagine I've got a library crate:

```
// library.rs
pub struct Dog;
pub trait Speak {
    fn speak(&self);
}
```

And two crates that use that library crate.

```
// bark.rs
extern crate library;
impl library::Speak for library::Dog {
    fn speak(&self) {
        println!("woof");
    }
}
```

```
// woof.rs
extern crate library;
impl library::Speak for library::Dog {
    fn speak(&self) {
        println!("bark");
    }
}
```

Now, for some reason, I want to use both of these libraries:

```
// main.rs
extern crate library;
extern crate woof;
extern crate bark;

fn main() {
   let rex = library::Dog;
   rex.speak();
}
```

What should this program output? There are two equally valid, indistinguishable implementations of `library::Speak` for `library::Dog`; there isn't a right answer. What's worse, if I depended on `woof` originally, and added `bark` later, my code would stop compiling, or - worse - start transparently doing the wrong thing. Conflicting trait impls are a Bad Thing™.

It gets worse when you add generics. If you have:

```
// barkgeneric.rs
extern crate library;
impl<T> library::Speak for T {
    fn speak(&self) {
        println!("woof");
    }
}
```

```
// woofgeneric.rs
extern crate library;
impl<T> library::Speak for T {
    fn speak(&self) {
        println!("bark");
    }
}
```

You now have an *infinite* number of conflicting trait impls. Whoops.

To avoid this problem, we have the orphan rules. The idea of the orphan rules is to make sure that any `impl Trait for Type` has one, and only one, place it can be put. That way, we don't have to worry about impl conflicts; they should be straight-up impossible, if the orphan rules are set up correctly.

The rules boil down to: when you `impl` a trait for a type, either the trait or the type has to come from the current crate. This makes all of my conflicting examples not work. `woof.rs` can't implement `library::speak` for `library::Dog`, because it neither of them come from its crate.

Similarly, you can't `impl<T> Index<Bounded> for [T; 4];`, because `[T; 4]` doesn't come from your crate, and `rustc` has decided that `Index<Bounded>` doesn't count as coming from your crate either.

It does, however, let your `impl Index<Bounded> for [i32; 4]` through, because in this case `Index<Bounded>` does come from you. It's possible that's a bug, but it's also possible that it's just intended behavior; the orphan rules are slightly more complex than what I've stated here, and they might be interacting in weird ways.

For more specifics, see [`rustc --explain E0117`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0117), [`rustc --explain E0210`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0210).