# Is there a way to get objects from a HashSet<Rc<T>> using a custom Borrow implementation other than creating a newtype?

Tags: rust

I have a `Student` struct which I store in a `HashSet` inside a `School` struct wrapped by `Rc` references so that they can be referenced by other internal structures in `School`:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Debug, Eq)]
struct Student {
    id: usize,
    // other stuff
}

impl Hash for Student {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        self.id.hash(state);
    }
}

impl PartialEq for Student {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.id == other.id
    }
}

struct School {
    students: HashSet<Rc<Student>>,
    // other stuff
}

impl School {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            students: HashSet::new(),
        }
    }
    fn add_student(&mut self) -> usize {
        let id = self.students.len();
        self.students.insert(Rc::new(Student { id }));
        id
    }
}
```

I wanted to implement `Borrow<usize> for Rc<Student>` so I could get references to students from the `HashSet` using their `id`:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

impl Borrow<usize> for Rc<Student> {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &usize {
        &self.id
    }
}

impl School {
    fn enrol(&mut self, student_id: usize) {
        // Need trait Borrow<usize> implemented for Rc<Student> for this to work
        if let Some(student) = self.students.get(&student_id) {
            println!("Enrolling {:?}", student);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't do that as `Borrow` is defined elsewhere, and the compiler is telling me I need to create a new type.

```
error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types
  --> src/main.rs:26:1
   |
26 | impl Borrow<usize> for Rc<Student> {
   | ^^^^^-------------^^^^^-----------
   | |    |                 |
   | |    |                 `std::rc::Rc` is not defined in the current crate
   | |    `usize` is not defined in the current crate
   | impl doesn't use only types from inside the current crate
   |
   = note: define and implement a trait or new type instead
```

I understand why a direct implementation of `Borrow for Rc<T>` is not possible but I'm wondering if there is a better way other than defining a new type just so I can implement `Borrow`. The goal is to have a shared reference but still be able to get objects from the `HashSet` by their `id`? Perhaps `Rc` isn't the best option here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do the coherence rules raise the error "the type parameter must be used as the type parameter for some local type"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38106639/why-do-the-coherence-rules-raise-the-error-the-type-parameter-must-be-used-as-t) TL;RD: the orphan rules forbids you to do that: you must create a newtype.

Comment: I understand why the trait can't be directly implemented but I'm wondering if there are  alternatives other than creating a new type. Perhaps another type of reference is more appropriate for this case or some other trick people use for shared references?